# Error handling multiple entry boxes at one time

Tags: python, error-handling

I am error handling the customer name, distance travelled, virus protection and wof and tune  for my program. What would I put in plce of 'something' or instead of using and if and else statement to run the enter_job function when there are no errors, so when none of the code inside the if something part is relevant to the data entered?
Thank you!

```
 if something:
    if self.name_entry_var.get() == "":
        self.name_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter customer name")
    
    if self.wof_var.get() == " ":
        self.wof_entry_error.configure(text = "Check YES or NO")
        
    try:
        if float(self.time_entry.get()) <= 0:
            self.time_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a positive number")
    except ValueError:
            self.time_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a number")
    try:
        if float(self.distance_entry.get()) <= 0:
            self.distance_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a positive number")
    except ValueError:
            self.distance_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a number")
 else:
    self.enter_job()
```

Edit:

If I do this then it will go straight into the enter_job function without checking the entries.

```
    try:
        self.enter_job()
    except:
        if self.name_entry_var.get() == "":
            self.name_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter customer name")
        
        if self.wof_var.get() == " ":
            self.wof_entry_error.configure(text = "Check YES or NO")
            
        try:
            if float(self.time_entry.get()) <= 0:
                self.time_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a positive number")
        except ValueError:
                self.time_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a number")
        try:
            if float(self.distance_entry.get()) <= 0:
                self.distance_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a positive number")
        except ValueError:
                self.distance_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a number")
```

Comment: I think the `try except` clause should manage that. look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/ for more info. what you're trying to check if running the code under the `else` block is raising an error right?

Comment: @ThunderCoder I have tried this also, but there is no error that would occur in the try part. So The code would never go to the except part

Answer (score -1):

The error handling should be done within the enter_job() function.
something like so:

```
def enter_job():
    if self.name_entry_var.get() == "":
        self.name_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter customer name")
        raise(self.name_entry_error)

    if self.wof_var.get() == " ":
        self.wof_entry_error.configure(text = "Check YES or NO")
        raise(self.wof_entry_error)

    try:
        if float(self.time_entry.get()) <= 0:
            self.time_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a positive number")
            raise(self.time_entry_error)

    except ValueError:
            self.time_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a number")
            raise(self.time_entry_error)

    try:
        if float(self.distance_entry.get()) <= 0:
            self.distance_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a positive number")
            raise(self.distance_entry_error)

    except ValueError:
        self.distance_entry_error.configure(text = "Enter a number")
        raise(self.distance_entry_error)
```

then running this line:

```
self.enter_job()
```

would return exceptions on it's own.

like so:

```
try:
    self.enter_job()
except Exception as e:
    raise(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but if I do this none of the errors that arise will be accounted for and will go straight into the enter_job function

Comment: @holly, you have to check that the input is fine within the function `enter_job()` and raise an error from within it if it isn't.  see my edited answer.

Comment: @holly, another thing you can do is forget the if statment, and just run all those `tries` one within the other, and then run the actual function call, after all `tries` passed succesfully.

Comment: @holly, if you find that this answer was helpful and solved your problem, please press the checkmark on it's left side, to accept it. why? this will help other users facing the same problem find the answer more easily. If not, please explain why it didn't so that I can make it better.